# rewrite using array filter

Tags: php, array-filter

How would I write the following `foreach` with some conditions using `array_filter`?

```php
 foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($this->request->getParam('category_id')) {
            if ($category->getCategoryId() == $this->request->getParam('category_id')) {
                $selectedCategory = $category;
                break;
            }
        } else {
             No category id in request. Select the first one.
            if (array_key_exists(0, $categoryTree) &&
                $category->getCategoryId() == $categoryTree[0]['id']
            ) {
                $selectedCategory = $category;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a better question - why do you want to do that? This code does not appear to be a good candidate for that modification. This code also is invalid and you aren't showing the origins of some of your variables.

Comment: `array_filter` would reduce an array to a subset of itself. So it might yield an array with one element, a dozen or none at all. Here you are selecting one element from an array, `array_filter` is not helpful in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

First off, using `array_filter` isn't helpful in this case as it reduces an array instead of selecting an element. But to show its principles, you could rewrite the code to something like this.

```
if($this->request->getParam('category_id')){
  $filteredCategories = array_filter($categories, function ($category) use ($this){
    return $category->getCategoryId() == $this->request->getParam('category_id');
  });
  if(count($filteredCategories)>0){
    return $filteredCategories[0];
  }
} else {
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an intersection function and not an array filter.

```
    function key_compare_func($key1, $key2) 
    { 
        if ($key1 == $key2->getCategoryId()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    $selectedCategory = array_intersect_ukey(
        $this>request>getParam('category_id'),
        $categories,
        'key_compare_func'
    )
```

For more information on the different array functions you can look at [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)